# Compare String with omitting the blank lines?

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have two strings and need to compare them without checking the blank lines...

**First string**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HELL_" 
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');
end;
```

**Second string**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USER1"."HELL_" 
as

begin

  dbms_output.put_line('Hello!');

end;
```

**code that I am using:**

```
                string text1 = "";
                string text2 = "";
                if (text1.Equals(text2 ))
                    MessageBox.Show("same");
                //no Exception
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("not");
                }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney The oracle procedures are the sample input. The second sample input includes blank lines.

Comment: I am using dbms_metadata.get_ddl to get ddl and store them inside string, but when this procedures are created with blank lines, I will get the blank lines inside my string and this make fails compare.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the lines by using  `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. The resulting `string[]` doesn't contain empty lines. Then [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) is useful.

```
string[] lines1 = text1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] lines2 = text2.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bool equal = lines1.SequenceEqual(lines2);
```

If the "empty" lines can contain white-spaces:

```
var lines1 = text1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0); 
var lines2 = text2.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0);
```

and if you want to ignore white-spaces at all:

```
var lines1 = text1.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0)
    .Select(l => l.Trim()); 
var lines2 = text2.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Trim().Length > 0)
    .Select(l => l.Trim());
```

and if you also want to ignore the case:

```
bool equal = lines1.SequenceEqual(lines2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the same line as the other answers (by also "sanitizing" first) but more generally treats "blank lines" as any whitespace-only lines bounded by CR, LF, or any combination of the two.

```
string RemoveEmptyLines (string s) {
    return Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:^|[\r\n]+)\s*?(?=(?:[\r\n]+|$))", "");
}

// Usage
RemoveEmptyLines(a) == RemoveEmptyLines(b)
```

The line-end characters (i.e. `[\r\n]`) may be expanded or refined as needed. This regular expression only process one blank line at a time (although all blank lines will be removed within the single Replace call) with a non-greedy quantifier and forward-lookahead. I find that this variation shows the intended operation more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case this would do the trick:

```
         if (firststring.Equals(secondstring.Text.Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n")))
             MessageBox.Show("same");
         //no Exception
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("not");
         }
```